# Group users and display the group on the profile page

Tags: 8, users, taxonomy-terms

How can I create a group/role/taxonomy term or anything else to group specific users ? I also want to display the "group/role/taxonomy term or anything else" on the users profile.

For example: I go to example.com/user/1 and I see all of his details **AND** that he has the administrator-"group/role/taxonomy term or anything else".

Thanks in advance (I am a noob here)

Comment: Welcome to the Drupal Stack Exchange community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles have a set of permissions, so they are ideal if you will have a set of users  editing certain types of content,
 like blog posts, and another group of user commenting on the content.
 You can create both new roles and permissions.

- Roles: `/admin/people/roles`
- Permissions: `/admin/people/permissions`

You can also add fields to the users, like a taxonomy where they choose whether they are a *dog person* or a *cat person*.

- Manage fields: `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`
- Manage form display: `/admin/config/people/accounts/form-display`

Then, you can choose which fields will be displayed on the *user profile page*

- Manage display: `/admin/config/people/accounts/display`

Comment: A combination out of roles and taxonomy terms worked great, thanks!